# Automatically detect higher slope in numerical data (within a certain range)

Tags: fitting, data

Suppose the dataset `data` is part of some simulations whose results should follow a certain model. Here is `data` and its `ListPlot` output:

```
data = {{35.5`, 2.3728787814994177`}, {36, 2.3850054342997815`}, {36.5`, 2.397785497763527`}, {37, 2.4110893800654356`}, {38, 2.438270603003388`}, {39, 2.46448993051198`}, {40, 2.490752253652167`}, {41, 2.5184494387690055`}, {42, 2.5505998125177354`}, {43, 2.5938608076497633`},{ 44, 2.673922539806348`}, {45, 2.793872375526594`}, {46, 2.776632708715904`}, {47, 2.7542888778717622`}, {48, 2.727803904015183`}, {49, 2.690492979770959`}};
```

[image: ListPlot of simulated data points]

There is a "kink" around `x=45` that can be detected via sign change in `Differences` applied to the data. But slightly in front of this kink there is a tremendous increase of slope compared to the linear regime (`x <= 42`).

My goal is to implement a routine that fits a `Piecewise` function to a much larger dataset. Depending on some parameters, there may or may not be a kink/increase of slopeness. Also, the boundaries (the x-values) for transition from "linear increase" -> "whatever" -> "linear decrease" depend on the parameters. For a single dataset I can for instance use

```
diff = Delete[Append[Differences@data[[;; , 2]], 1]/data[[;; , 2]], -1];
pos = Flatten[Position[diff, _?(Abs[#] > 0.016 &)]];
ListPlot[Take[data, First@pos]]
```

[image: reduced to linear regime]

to manually find the transition "linear increase" -> "whatever" via looking at the behavior of `diff`. However, since I have many such datasets, that would require manually adjusting the border in relative change (here `0.016`) to fix to a certain region. What I want is something that for instance successively compares elements of `diff` and recognizes when, say, the relative change in difference of previous $n$ elements is lower than that from $n$ to $n+1$.

The method does not have to be super efficient, since each dataset has `Length` of 100 at most. I also only want to find the transition from linear increase to something else - if it exists (sometimes data might end inside the linear regime).

Is there maybe a built-in function for this job? Or how can my idea/something else be coded up reliably?

Answer (score 6):

Create an interpolating function from your data:

```
fi = Interpolation@data
```

How the interpolating function looks:

```
Plot[fi@x, {x, 35.5, 49}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Plot the gradient of the gradient `fi''` of the interpolating function:

```
Plot[fi''@x, {x, 35.5, 49}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Select those values where the 2nd differential is relatively large:

```
Select[{fi''[First@#], First@#} & /@ data, First@# > .01 &]
```

> > {{0.0111106, 42}, {0.0368007, 43}, {0.0398881, 44}}

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. Interpolation is quite handy here.

Comment: No problem, maybe `Interpolation` is enough for your needs?

Comment: I will implement it into my routine today or tomorrow and see how it actually performs. Also, I wanted to wait a day or so before I accept to see what others might come up with, if that's what you were after?

Comment: No just wondered if `Interpolate` gave you enough, very happy for you to wait, I suspect there will be better solutions :)

Comment: I wonder if `GradientFilter[]` might be more suitable here…

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Good suggestion. I'll take a look at it

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Took a look and it works quite nice! Final results are mainly the same as for `Interpolation`, but I guess interpolating in general requires more ressources (although not of any importance in this case)

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility, which avoids interpolation, is the usage of DerivativeFilter, in particular to take the second derivative:

```
{x, y} = Transpose@ data;
d2y = DerivativeFilter[y, {2}];
kinkx = First@ Pick[data, d2y, Min[d2y]];
```

The result is:

> {45,2.793872376}

Comment: This will find the kink, not the position where slope increases. However, it can also be done with `DerivativeFilter` so thanks for this hint :)

Comment: slopeincx = First@ Pick[data, d2y, Max[d2y]] might get the other information